# Why is there a javascriptsDir parameter for grunt-contrib-compass?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

There is a [JavascriptsDir](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#javascriptsdir) parameter in grunt-contrib-compass.

But the documentation is not clear on the usage of this parameter.

What is it used for ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grunt-contrib-compass is a nice bridge that allows you to use Compass (a ruby project) with grunt. `javascriptsDir` corresponds to the Compass option `javascripts_dir`.

Compass doesn't actually make use of the `javascripts_dir` option itself, but the option is there for compass extensions to make use of. This is so that you won't end up with multiple extensions that all need to know where your javascript files are that all use different option names.

[Here's the explanation straight from one of the Compass developers.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/compass-users/rjAntZ8RZgs)